# HTML DOM delete row and calculation problem

Tags: javascript, dom-events, append, delete-row, calculation

I am working in a html file that contains a table and by clicking 'Add rows' the rows are being added and the total sum of all the 'Total price' is being stored in 'Sub total'. But when I want to remove or delete a row the the proper value of 'Sub total' is not coming. Where is the problem and what's the solution?? I am pasting the necessary lines.

```js
function calculate(value) {

  var st1 = +document.getElementById("st").value;
  var t1 = +document.getElementById("tax1").value;

  var tax1 = +((st1 * t1) / 100);

  document.getElementById("tax2").value = tax1;

  var discBill = +document.getElementById("discBill").value;
  var np = (st1 + tax1) - discBill;
  document.getElementById("net_payable").value = np;
}

const table = document.getElementById("mytable");

document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", e => {
  var row = table.querySelector("tr").cloneNode(true);
  row.querySelectorAll("input").forEach(inp => inp.value = "");
  table.append(row);
});

table.addEventListener("input", e => {

  let gtotal = 0;
  let totaldiscount = 0;
  table.querySelectorAll("tr").forEach(row => {


    const price = +row.querySelector(".Price").value;
    const discount1 = +row.querySelector(".Discount1").value;
    const percent = discount1 / 100;
    const discount2 = price * percent;
    const total = price - discount2;
    row.querySelector(".Discount2").value = discount2;
    row.querySelector(".totalPrice").value = total;
    gtotal += total;
    totaldiscount += discount2;
    document.querySelector(".Subtotal").value = gtotal;
    document.querySelector(".disc1st").value = totaldiscount;



  });
  var closebtns = document.getElementsByClassName("close");
  var i;


  for (i = 0; i < closebtns.length; i++) {
    closebtns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {

      this.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
      var totalST = +document.getElementById("st").value;
      var currentPrice = +document.getElementById("tp").value;
      var currentST = totalST - currentPrice;
      document.getElementById("st").value = currentST;



    });
  }



});
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <table>
    <tbody id="mytable">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>Category</label>
          <span>*</span>
          <select class="form-control Category">
            <option>Select</option>
            <option>A</option>
            <option>B</option>
            <option>C</option>
            <option>D</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label>Test Name</label>
          <select class="form-control TestName">
            <option>Select</option>
            <option>A</option>
            <option>B</option>
            <option>C</option>
            <option>D</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label>Price</label>
          <input type="text" id="Price" name="Price[]" class="form-control Price" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <label>Discount(%)</label>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
              <input type="text" name="discount1[]" class="form-control Discount1" />
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-6">
              <input type="text" name="discount2[]" class="form-control Discount2" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label>Total Price</label>
          <input type="text" name="totalPrice[]" id="tp" class="form-control totalPrice">
        </td>
        <td class="close">

          <span class="close">x</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<button type="button" id="add">Add rows</button>





<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-7"></div>
  <div class="col-lg-5" id="BillSum">
    <label>Bill summary</label><br>

    <div class="row">

      <label>Sub total</label>
      <input type="text" id="st" name="Sub total" class="form-control Subtotal" value="0.00">

    </div>


    <label>Tax</label><br>
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col=lg-6">
        <input type="text" id="tax1" name="tax1" class="form-control tax1" onkeyup="calculate(this.value);">
      </div>

      <div class="col=lg-6">
        <input type="text" id="tax2" name="tax2" class="form-control tax2">
      </div>

    </div>


    <label>Discount(-)</label><br>
    <div class="row">
      <input type="text" id="discBill" name="Discount_Bill" class="form-control disc1st" onkeyup="calculate(this.value);">

    </div>

    <label>Net payable</label><br>
    <div class="row">
      <input type="text" id="net_payable" name="Net_Payable" class="form-control disc2st">

    </div>

    <label>Received amount</label><br>
    <div class="row">
      <input type="text" id="received_amount" name="Received_amount" class="form-control ra" placeholder="Enter payment amount">

    </div>


    <label>Payvia</label><br>
    <div class="row">
      <select class="form-control">
        <option>Select</option>
        <option>A</option>
        <option>B</option>
        <option>C</option>
        <option>D</option>
      </select>

    </div>

    <label>Remarks</label><br>
    <div class="row">
      <input type="text" name="Sub total" class="form-control" placeholder="Write your remarks">

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I have made some key changes which was necessary to solve your problem:

1. Instead of listening to `input` changes, I have modified the code to listen to `change` like so `table.addEventListener("change",()=>{})` where you will be able to capture the input only after the user press enter or leave focus state.
2. Listening for `click` events from close button inside the table event listener is a huge mistake since every time there is a change in input, duplicate events get registered since you are not removing the already registered events which gives you unexpected results. So instead, I have attached the `onclick()` event directly to the close button and created `removeRow` function and moved all codes of close button listener with some changes added.
3. I have added **.close-button** class to span and added onclick event on it instead of `<td>` tag.
4. Upon clicking close button, remove the row elements completely instead of `display: none` because it won't stop the event listener from looping over the element since it is still in the DOM which results in inconsistent output of your variable values.
5. Try not to use same id values in the same document. Since you are cloning the rows, you end up getting different rows but with same id value.
6. Also try to use native `parseInt()` instead of `+` for performance reasons if you are doing CPU intensive operations in future projects.

Finally, I have added comments wherever necessary. Feel free for follow up comments if you face any problem. You can run the code here itself and see if it works.

```js
function calculate(value) {

  var st1 = +document.getElementById("st").value;
  var t1 = +document.getElementById("tax1").value;

  var tax1 = +((st1 * t1) / 100);

  document.getElementById("tax2").value = tax1;

  var discBill = +document.getElementById("discBill").value;
  var np = (st1 + tax1) - discBill;
  document.getElementById("net_payable").value = np;
}

const table = document.getElementById("mytable");

document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", e => {
  var row = table.querySelector("tr").cloneNode(true);
  row.querySelectorAll("input").forEach(inp => inp.value = "");
  table.append(row);
});

table.addEventListener("change", e => {
  let gtotal = 0;
  let totaldiscount = 0;
  table.querySelectorAll("tr").forEach(row => {
    let price = row.querySelector(".Price").value;
    let discount1 = row.querySelector(".Discount1").value;
    let percent = discount1 / 100;
    let discount2 = price * percent;
    let total = price - discount2;
    row.querySelector(".Discount2").value = discount2;
    row.querySelector(".totalPrice").value = total;
    gtotal += total;
    totaldiscount += discount2;
    document.querySelector("#st").value = gtotal;
    document.querySelector(".disc1st").value = totaldiscount;
  });
});


function removeRow(event) {
  let totalST = document.getElementById("st").value;
  // make sure you are getting the total price of the current row
  let currentPrice = event.currentTarget.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('#tp').value;
  let currentST = totalST - currentPrice;
  document.querySelector("#st").value = currentST;
  event.currentTarget.parentNode.parentNode.remove(); // remove the row completely
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <table>
    <tbody id="mytable">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>Category</label>
          <span>*</span>
          <select class="form-control Category">
            <option>Select</option>
            <option>A</option>
            <option>B</option>
            <option>C</option>
            <option>D</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label>Test Name</label>
          <select class="form-control TestName">
            <option>Select</option>
            <option>A</option>
            <option>B</option>
            <option>C</option>
            <option>D</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label>Price</label>
          <input type="text" id="Price" name="Price[]" class="form-control Price" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <label>Discount(%)</label>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
              <input type="text" name="discount1[]" class="form-control Discount1" />
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-6">
              <input type="text" name="discount2[]" class="form-control Discount2" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label>Total Price</label>
          <input type="text" name="totalPrice[]" id="tp" class="form-control totalPrice">
        </td>
        <td class="close">

          <span class="close-button" onclick="removeRow(event)">x</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<button type="button" id="add">Add rows</button>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-7"></div>
  <div class="col-lg-5" id="BillSum">
    <label>Bill summary</label><br>

    <div class="row">

      <label>Sub total</label>
      <input type="text" id="st" name="Sub total" class="form-control Subtotal" value="0">

    </div>
    <label>Tax</label><br>
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col=lg-6">
        <input type="text" id="tax1" name="tax1" class="form-control tax1" onkeyup="calculate(this.value);">
      </div>

      <div class="col=lg-6">
        <input type="text" id="tax2" name="tax2" class="form-control tax2">
      </div>

    </div>
    <label>Discount(-)</label><br>
    <div class="row">
      <input type="text" id="discBill" name="Discount_Bill" class="form-control disc1st" onkeyup="calculate(this.value);">

    </div>

    <label>Net payable</label><br>
    <div class="row">
      <input type="text" id="net_payable" name="Net_Payable" class="form-control disc2st">

    </div>

    <label>Received amount</label><br>
    <div class="row">
      <input type="text" id="received_amount" name="Received_amount" class="form-control ra" placeholder="Enter payment amount">
    </div>
    <label>Payvia</label><br>
    <div class="row">
      <select class="form-control">
        <option>Select</option>
        <option>A</option>
        <option>B</option>
        <option>C</option>
        <option>D</option>
      </select>

    </div>
    <label>Remarks</label><br>
    <div class="row">
      <input type="text" name="Sub total" class="form-control" placeholder="Write your remarks">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```